# How can I access 2 databases in single SQL statement (table names, DB names the same) OLEDB

Tags: sql, database, vb.net, ms-access

I have several versions of a database on the same computer. These have the same
DB Name, Fields, and table names. I am trying to merge them as different DB's may have some differences (ie additional records, or field value changes)

I have 2 connections to 2 different databases on my PC (not using a server)

I would like to access 2 DBs to get the differences using SQL like:

```
(SELECT * FROM [].DB1Table  EXCEPT  SELECT * FROM [].DB2Table)
 UNION ALL 
(SELECT * FROM [].DB2Table  EXCEPT SELECT * FROM [].DB1Table)
```

I have seen solutions such as: (this is included to show one example of how to qualify tables to access 2 different tables.)

```
select t1.ID, t1.Name, t2.Name
from [DBOne].[dbo].[TableOne] as t1
inner join [DBbTwo].[dbo].[TableTwo] as t2 on t1.ID = t2.ID
```

I am trying to get the differences between the 2 tables [SELECT FROM DB1Table  EXCEPT  SELECT * FROM DB2Table) and then go through and merge the differences,
but I am unsure how to do this in VB Net with my OLEDB DB Connections.
(Both databases are Access Databases)

Is there a way to accomplish this?

Comment: The connection connects to one DB.  There are ways to link and import tables in other DBs, but it is unclear *what* you are trying to do.  A JOIN and a UNION are 2 different things.  Also, hover over your tag choices and reconsider.  Please read [ask] and take the [tour]

Comment: you can't compare tables using single query if they are located on different sql servers.

Comment: @AKunin You can with linked servers, or as shown in Parfait's answer.

Answer (score 1):

Consider connecting to the external database inline to the query which is an available feature in the MS Access SQL dialect. And use `NOT EXISTS` clause to retrieve unmatched records. Below assumes one connection to *DB1* where *DB2's* table is referenced externally.

```sql
SELECT * FROM myTable t1
WHERE NOT EXISTS 
  (SELECT 1 FROM myTable t2 IN 'C:\Path\To\External\Database.accdb'
   WHERE t1.ID = t2.ID)

UNION

SELECT * FROM myTable t2 IN 'C:\Path\To\External\Database.accdb' 
WHERE NOT EXISTS 
  (SELECT 1 FROM myTable t1
   WHERE t2.ID = t1.ID)
```

Comment: I'm trying this out - will report back